# Replacing content of default header of v-data-table

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a Vue application that is using Vuetify 2.x `v-data-table` component. Inside the v-data-table component is a template for the defined slot `:header`. Within the template is another custom defined slot.

```html
    <v-data-table>
        <template v-slot:header="props">
            <tr>
                <slot name="hdrCheckbox">
                    <th><v-checkbox :input-value="props.all" color="#c79121" :indeterminate="props.indeterminate" primary hide-details @click.stop="toggleAllSelected"></v-checkbox></th>
                </slot>
    
                <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text"
                    :class="['column sortable', dataTable.options.sortDesc ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === dataTable.options.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
                    @click="$emit('change-sort', header.value)">
                    <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
                    {{ header.text }}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

```html
    <data-table>
        <template #hdrCheckbox="props"><th class="empty"></th></template>
    </data-table>
```

This is the markup that the component renders:

```html
    <tr>
        <th class="empty"></th>
    </tr>
    <thead class="v-data-table-header">
        <tr>
            <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Topic" class="text-start">
                <span>Topic</span>
            </th>
            <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Current Interval" class="text-start">
                <span>Current Interval</span>
            </th>
            <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Interval Benchmark: Sorted ascending. Activate to sort descending." aria-sort="ascending" class="text-start sortable active asc">
                <span>Interval Benchmark</span>
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon mdi mdi-arrow-up theme--light" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            </th>
            <th role="columnheader" scope="col" aria-label="Add Date: Not sorted. Activate to sort ascending." aria-sort="none" class="text-start sortable">
                <span>Add Date</span>
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-data-table-header__icon mdi mdi-arrow-up theme--light" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Why does the content of the custom defined slot `hdrCheckbox` render outside of the `thead` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's how `v-data-table` works

It may feel strange first but overriding `header` slot of `v-data-table` **does not** replace it's default header content. You need to use `hide-default-header` prop to do that. And content of `header` slot is placed **before** default header content...

Also check the documentation for `header` slot - parameter passed into it is object `{ props: {...}, on: {...}}` so using it like `<template v-slot:header="props">` wont work (`props.headers` does not exist, `props.props.headers` does). Use `<template v-slot:header="{ props }">` instead....